# Waiting on condition variable with timeout: lock not reacquired in time

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have an `asyncio.Condition` named `cond`. I wish to wait on it, but only for so long before giving up. As `asyncio.Condition.wait` does not take a timeout, this cannot be done directly. [The docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-sync.html) state that `asyncio.wait_for` should be used to wrap and provide a timeout instead:

> The asyncio.wait_for() function can be used to cancel a task after a timeout.

Thus, we arrive at the following solution:

```
async def coro():
    print("Taking lock...")
    async with cond:
        print("Lock acquired.")
        print("Waiting!")
        await asyncio.wait_for(cond.wait(), timeout=999)
        print("Was notified!")
    print("Lock released.")
```

---

Now assume that `coro` itself is cancelled five seconds after being run. This throws `CancelledError` in the `wait_for`, which cancels the `cond.wait` before re-raising the error. The error then propagates to `coro`, which due to the `async with` block, implicitly attempts to release the lock in `cond`. However, the lock is not currently held; `cond.wait` has been cancelled but hasn't had a chance to process that cancellation and re-acquire the lock. Thus, we get an ugly exception like the following:

```
Taking lock...
Lock acquired.
Waiting!
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<coro() done, defined at [REDACTED]> exception=RuntimeError('Lock is not acquired.',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [REDACTED], in coro
    await asyncio.wait_for(cond.wait(), timeout=999)
  [REDACTED], in wait_for
    yield from waiter
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  [REDACTED], in coro
    print("Was notified!")
  [REDACTED], in coro
    res = func(*args, **kw)
  [REDACTED], in __aexit__
    self.release()
  [REDACTED], in release
    raise RuntimeError('Lock is not acquired.')
RuntimeError: Lock is not acquired.
```

In other words, whilst handling the `CancelledError`, `coro` raised a `RuntimeError` from trying to release a lock that wasn't held. The reason the stacktrace shows the `print("Was notified!")` line is because that is the last line of the offending `async with` block.

---

<del>This doesn't feel like something I can fix; I'm starting to suspect it's a bug in the library itself. However, I can't think of any way to avoid the issue or create a workaround, so any ideas would be appreciated.</del>

Whilst writing this question and investigating further, I stumbled into similar problems on the Python bug tracker, ended up inspecting the `asyncio` source code, and determined that this is, in fact, a bug in `asyncio` itself.

I've submitted it to the issue tracker [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue39032) for those who have the same problem, and answered my own question with a workaround that I have created.

---

**EDIT:** As requested by ParkerD, here is the full runnable example that produces the above issue:

**EDIT 2:** updated example to use the new `asyncio.run` and `asyncio.create_task` features from Python 3.7+

```
import asyncio

async def coro():
    cond = asyncio.Condition()
    print("Taking lock...")
    async with cond:
        print("Lock acquired.")
        print("Waiting!")
        await asyncio.wait_for(cond.wait(), timeout=999)
        print("Was notified!")
    print("Lock released.")

async def cancel_after_5(c):
    task = asyncio.create_task(c)
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    task.cancel()
    await asyncio.wait([task])

asyncio.run(cancel_after_5(coro()))
```

Comment: Could you post the code calling `coro`? When I run and cancel it everything seems to work fine

Comment: @ParkerD I've added a runnable example.

Comment: So, if you do `asyncio.run(cancel_after_5(coro()))` instead of `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(cancel_after_5(coro()))` it works fine for me, which is interesting.

Comment: @ParkerD just checked that out. It looks like the issue was assigning `cond = asyncio.Condition()` outside of the event loop. If you use `asyncio.run`, it creates its own event loop, which is NOT the one that `cond` saw, so you get a `got Future attached to a different loop` exception instead of the expected `CancelledError` or `RuntimeError: Lock is not acquired`. For some reason, this is silent unless you explicitly catch and print it. I'll edit the post to give a runnable example with `asyncio.run`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated at the end of the question, I've determined that the issue is actually a bug in the library. I'll reiterate that the issue tracker for that bug is [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue39032), and present my workaround.

The following function is based on `wait_for` itself (source [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b738237d6792acba85b1f6e6c8993a812c7fd815/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py)), and is a version of it specialised for waiting on conditions, with the added guarantee that cancelling it is safe.

Calling `wait_on_condition_with_timeout(cond, timeout)` is roughly equivalent to `asyncio.wait_for(cond.wait(), timeout)`.

```
async def wait_on_condition_with_timeout(condition: asyncio.Condition, timeout: float) -> bool:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    # Create a future that will be triggered by either completion or timeout.
    waiter = loop.create_future()

    # Callback to trigger the future. The varargs are there to consume and void any arguments passed.
    # This allows the same callback to be used in loop.call_later and wait_task.add_done_callback,
    # which automatically passes the finished future in.
    def release_waiter(*_):
        if not waiter.done():
            waiter.set_result(None)

    # Set up the timeout
    timeout_handle = loop.call_later(timeout, release_waiter)

    # Launch the wait task
    wait_task = loop.create_task(condition.wait())
    wait_task.add_done_callback(release_waiter)

    try:
        await waiter  # Returns on wait complete or timeout
        if wait_task.done():
            return True
        else:
            raise asyncio.TimeoutError()

    except (asyncio.TimeoutError, asyncio.CancelledError):
        # If timeout or cancellation occur, clean up, cancel the wait, let it handle the cancellation,
        # then re-raise.
        wait_task.remove_done_callback(release_waiter)
        wait_task.cancel()
        await asyncio.wait([wait_task])
        raise

    finally:
        timeout_handle.cancel()
```

The crucial part is that if a timeout or cancellation occurs, the method waits for the condition to re-acquire the lock before re-raising the exception:

```
except (asyncio.TimeoutError, asyncio.CancelledError):
        # If timeout or cancellation occur, clean up, cancel the wait, let it handle the cancellation,
        # then re-raise.
        wait_task.remove_done_callback(release_waiter)
        wait_task.cancel()
        await asyncio.wait([wait_task])  # This line is missing from the real wait_for
        raise
```

I've tested this on Python 3.6.9 and it works perfectly. The same bug exists in 3.7 and 3.8 too, so I imagine it is also useful for those versions. If you want to know when the bug will be fixed, check the issue tracker above. If you want a version for things other than `Condition`s, it should be trivial to change the parameter and `create_task` line.